# How to configure putty for 3 hop ssh tunnel connection?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, tunnel

How do I configure Putty for a 3 hop SSH tunnel connection? I know how to configure Putty for a 2 hop SSH tunnel connection, but now I am looking for a way to configure it with 3 hops. Can someone explain to me the procedure on how we can achieve it?

For two hops, I am following the below method.

Windows 10 (Putty) --> Linux Machine1 (192.168.1.100) --> Linux Machine2 (192.168.1.150)

- In the session window given the destination address (192.168.1.150) and port 22.
- In the Proxy option, I have given the intermediate server IP (192.168.1.100) and port 22.
- Also for the telnet command, I have given the following.

> plink -agent -l %user %proxyhost -nc %host:%port

The above setup works fine for 2 hops. But now my requirement is a 3 hop SSH tunnel. How do i modify the current one and add 1 more hop?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you are just wanting to connect to an additional machine on the same network as Linux Machines 1/2 or if you need to jump to another network beyond them (for example Machine 4 on 172.22.1.x).

If you're simply trying to get to another machine on the same 192.168.1.x network as Linux Machine 1/2, use an actual [SSH Tunnel](http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html) (found under Putty's `Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels` menu).  You can set up multiple tunnels to as many machines as you need to.

If you are actually trying to get to a third network, you can open up another instance of Putty that connects via a tunnel defined on your original Putty instance.

- Define a tunnel in Putty that forwards a port on your local machine (2222 for example) to Port 22 on Linux Machine2
- Then open another Putty instance on your Windows Machine that uses the tunnel (i.e. connect to Localhost:2222) AND defines a new tunnel to forward an additional port (2223 for example) to Port 22 on Machine4 (your 3rd hop).
- Open one more instance of Putty and connect to Localhost:2223 to access Machine4

I've only ever done this with 2 hops so I don't know how it will perform.  It's not an ideal solution, but it may work if this is your only option.

Edit: If you're not limited to Windows/Putty, [this (Transparent Multi-hop SSH)](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html) may do what you want.  If you are limited to Windows, [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) may have some more flexible SSH tools.

Comment: Yes my requirement is to get to a third network. I will try out this solution.. But just thinking if this could be configured in single putty instance.. Than creating 2 different instances.

Comment: Actually host b can be accessed only from host a and host c can only be accessed from hostb. So from my windows machine i need to pass 3 hops to reach the destination (hosta, hostb, hostc).

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this without multiple Putty instances.  Basically, you're using Putty as a virtual router to connect networks that aren't physically connected.

Answer (score 2):

## Multihop tunnel with PuTTY

PuTTY -> jHost1 (jIP1) -> jHost2 (jIP2) -> Destination (dIP)

**Quick answer:**

Your approach is correct, just use plink to jHost1 as a local proxy for the plink to jHost2:

`plink user2@jHost2 -nc dIP:dPort -proxycmd "plink user1@jIP1 -loghost jHost1 -nc jIP2:jPort2"`

**More elaboration and caveats:**

1. Use `-t` (in both plinks) so that your **terminal signals** work (since you are not invoking a remote shell on the jump hosts)
2. There are **passwords in plain text** (in command line / PuTTY config) when `-l user -pw password` is used (doesn't matter if you use PuTTY placeholder %proxypass).

   - use `-i` to specify a private-key without passphrase (since the standard I/O is used by PuTTY and you will not be able to enter it)
   - or use `-agent` to use keys from Pageant
   - agent forwarding (`-a`) is not required because the plinks run locally.
3. Run the plinks from the command line for the first time to see if there are no additional questions. Usually you get an "**Incoming packet was garbled on decryption**" error, if plink asks you to import jHost's SSH key.
4. Mind the usage of `jHost` and `jIP`. By `jHost` I mean the **logical hostname** for plink's "known_hosts" key lookup (PuTTY storage in Windows registry). `jIP` is the next hop's name/IP accessible from the current hop. (You are usually connecting from other network unable to reslove `jHost`.)

   - The outer plink can simply use `jHost2` because the connection is proxied and there is no DNS lookup at all.
   - The inner plink has to use the `jIP1` to connect, `-loghost jHost1` for the local key lookup and `-nc jIP2:jPort2` to NetCat to the next hop.
5. If you need to use **TCP forwarding** on the Destination (which has to be allowed), the only thing you need to do is configure it in PuTTY as if there were no jump hosts at all. This is because the SSH connection to Destination in tunneled through jHost2 and this connection in turn through jHost1, and the jump hosts have no insight to the tunnel.

   - As opposed to just sshing to jump host and running ssh again to reach Destination, where you need to use `<enter>~C<enter>` sequence to escape to the jump host's ssh client and use `-L`/`-R` commands to add tunnels dynamically.

**No TCP forwarding**

`plink -nc` (`ssh -W` equivalent) is a local proxy which TCP-forwards its standard I/O via a jump host. If you are unable to allow TCP forwarding on the jump hosts, as a limited workaround you can ssh to `jHost1` and use `ssh user2@jHost2 -t ssh user@Destination` in "Connection -> SSH -> Remote Command" with no proxy settings.

This way you start a new ssh client on the jump host (and the keys have to be present / passwords retyped / agent forwarded, configuration / known_hosts duplicated...).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, but I couldn't find this anywhere else when searching for multi-hop tunnel with PuTTY. I especially appreciate the details in the elaboration/caveats.