# How would I replicate these ssh commands using Putty or plink for a windows computer?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, plink

**I am trying to understand the connection flow of the following setup, so that I may replicate the remote commands using windows putty or plink.**

I have 3 computers:
local - intermediate - remote

On the local computer I am running the following command

```
ssh -R 10022:localhost:22 -i /location/to/key i-user@intermediate-ip -p 22
```

From my understanding, the above command allows anyone on the intermediate server connecting via port 10022 to be tunneled back to the local computer through port 22.

The next command is executed by someone on the remote computer

```
ssh -D 3456 -J i-user@intermediate-ip -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa local-user@localhost -p 10022 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This part confuses me. Basically we are sshing into the intermediate server and then from there sshing into the local computer via port 10022? But what about the dynamic port forwarding? How does that work? Is it executed on the local computer? How does it flow through the tunnel?

I believe that [How to configure putty for 3 hop ssh tunnel connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/1126045/how-to-configure-putty-for-3-hop-ssh-tunnel-connection) answers how to get from the remote to the intermediate using plink but **I still don't understand how to make that last jump from the intermediate to the local AND implement dynamic port forwarding.**

---

In case I haven't explained it well enough, here is the verbose output for the remote computer commands

The debug log shows

```
Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -l i-user -vvv -W '[%h]:%p' intermediate-ip
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -l username -vvv -W '[localhost]:10022' intermediate-ip
resolving "intermediate-ip" port 22
Connecting to intermediate-ip [intermediate-ip] port 22.
Connection established.
Authenticated to intermediate-ip ([intermediate-ip]:22).
ssh_init_stdio_forwarding: localhost:10022
Authenticating to localhost:10022 as 'd-user'
put_host_port: [localhost]:10022
Authenticated to localhost (via proxy).
Local connections to LOCALHOST:3456 forwarded to remote address socks:0
Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 3456
Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 3456
```

Comment: What you're referring to is an SSH multi-hop.  In PuTTY, it's configured in Category > Connection > Proxy - _local proxy command_ and two PuTTY profiles are required (Intermediate & Remote). The Intermediate profile will be a normally configured SSH profile, but for the Remote, the Proxy section's _local proxy command_ will reference the Intermediate profile's name.  Both the Intermediate and Remote SSH keys will need to be loaded into Pageant. I don't have the time to format an answer, but if you search "multihop ssh" or "bastion server" on Superuser, you should be able to find some examples.

Comment: @JW0914 Thank you. Can you tell me in which section I'd put the dynamic port forwarding? This is the part that is confusing me the most.

Comment: Actually I think I can do it in tunnels section in the intermediate profile. Anyway thanks for the pointers :)

Comment: It would be configured in the Category > Connection > SSH > Tunnels section of the intermediate profile